# npm install doesn't install typescript (on mac)

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, installation, zsh

I try to use typescript as a local dependency. What I want, is to have it checked into my devDependencies, and use it via an npm script, after npm install'ing it.

What I find is, that typescript *(and webpack-cli for that matter as well)* won't be installed if I try this on my machine.

Steps to reproduce (as a shell script):

```sh
mkdir myproject
cd myproject
npm init --yes
npm i --save-dev typescript
```

now, `cat package.json` will confirm, that typescript is checked into our devdependencies,  but even after another `npm install`, the `node_modules` directory will remain completly empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

- Node version: `v16.14.2`
- npm version: `8.5.0`
- OS: macOs Monterey

(I previously encountered that this happens no matter which version I am using)

The Computer is freshly set up, only thing I did is log into a private npm repository

#### This seems to work fine in linux

running these steps inside linux (docker container with node image)
will result in a different result: `ls node_modules` will show `typescript`

#### This also works fine on a coworkers mac

I am therefore a bit at loss about what is going on here

#### This also works fine on my machine, if not using zsh but bash.

I am using oh my zsh

Comment: `cd my project` is typo, right? (should be `cd myproject`)

Comment: Thank you @AlekseyL. yes it it. Now I have fixed the post

Answer (score 1):

I had `NODE_ENV=production` set as an env variable, coming from a rather buried env script.

not clever, but hard to find